# Formatting the result of a query in google sheets UTC to local date

Tags: date, google-sheets, format

I built a formula to retrieve data from another sheet the following formula works, however, T is coming back as a UTC date time string and I would like the Date part only and in the format dd mmm yyyy e.g. 01 Jan 2018

UTC format being returned is 2018-11-14 10:06:32.416206+00:00

```
=iferror(
QUERY(DATA!A:AA, "
SELECT A,B, D, T, N 
WHERE( AA CONTAINS '" &  lower(B9) & "' AND L = TRUE) 
Order by T Asc"))
```

I have tried adding

format T ‘dd-mmm-yyyy' but I guess I'm doing it wrong!

```
=iferror(
QUERY(DATA!A:AA, "
SELECT A,B, D, T, N 
WHERE( AA CONTAINS '" &  lower(B9) & "' AND L = TRUE) 
Order by T Asc format T ‘dd-mmm-yyyy'"))
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you extend your query by one column and in AB apply, copied down:

```
=left(T2,10)+mid(T2,12,15)-right(T2,5)
```

then use your first attempt with `T` replaced by `AB` and the dates in the result formatted:

```
dd mmm yyyy
```

Comment: Is there any way of building this into my formula so it returns the correct date format without having two date columns?